# fb-hydra: How to get inner configurations to inherit outer configuration fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, config, fb-hydra

I am trying to write a hierarchical configuration structure such that config files in the inner directories inherit from the config files in the outer directories. For example, in the following scenario

```
upper_config
|
|-middle_config
|   |
|   |-lower_config
```

I would like `middle_config` to be able to inherit & override the parameters of `upper_config`, and `lower_config` to be able to inherit & override the parameters of both `middle_config` and `upper_config`.

One solution would be to write a configuration parser such that outer modules are read first, and as inner modules are read they overwrite the fields in the outer modules.

However, I would like to use Hydra (or some other tool, open to suggestions) for all of the added conveniences. I've read the documentation front to back a few times, and though it feels like either config groups or packages directives should be able to handle this, I can't quite piece it together.

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64593916/how-to-do-file-over-rides-in-hydra) post asks a very similar question, but the answer hasn't enlightened me, and it seems that the person who asked the question decided to implement a version of the config parser I described above.

I am hoping that there is a way for an inner config file's `package` directive to be changed to point to a parent configuration and somehow inherit its default list that way.

Comment: As an alternative to my answer below (which uses Hydra), this might be achieved using plain OmegaConf as follows: 1) Use Python's `os.walk` function to get a list of yaml files, 2) Use some heuristic to order these files according to your preference for which should be merged on top of which others, 3) Call `OmegaConf.load(filename)` on each file to produce a list of OmegaConf objects, and 4) call `cfg = OmegaConf.merge(*list_of_config_objects)` to merge the collected config objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose we have the following files:

```
my_app.py
outer/conf1.yaml
outer/middle/conf2.yaml
outer/middle/inner/conf3.yaml
```

To make things concrete, here are the contents of `my_app.py`:

```py
import hydra, omegaconf

@hydra.main(config_path="outer", config_name="conf1")
def my_app(cfg) -> None:
    print(omegaconf.OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))

my_app()
```

## TLDR

If your `yaml` files just contain plain data (i.e. no defaults lists or package directives), the most flexible approach to dynamically composing your config at the command line looks like this:

```sh
$ python my_app.py +middle@_global_=conf2 +middle/inner@_global_=conf3
```

This will merge `outer/middle/conf2.yaml` on top of `outer/conf1.yaml`, then merge `outer/middle/inner/conf3.yaml` on top of that. The `@_global_` keyword means that the input configs should be merged at the top level instead of being nested according to the names of their containing directories.

## Now for the details...

In answering this question, I might use some features from the recent release candidate for Hydra 1.1:

```py
>>> import hydra
>>> hydra.__version__
'1.1.0.rc1'
```

There are a few approaches we could take to overriding our outer configuration with middle/inner configuration:

- Use the defaults list to specify a package.
- Use a package header to specify a package.
- Use a command-line package override to specify a package (this is the method used in the TLDR section above)

Here are the details for each approach:

### Use the defaults list to specify a package.

Suppose we have the following:
In `outer/conf1.yaml`:

```yaml
defaults:
  - _self_
  - middle@_here_: conf2
a: 1
b: 2
```

In `outer/middle/conf1.yaml`:

```yaml
defaults:
  - _self_
  - inner@_here_: conf3
b: 3
c: 4
```

In `outer/middle/inner/conf3.yaml`:

```yaml
c: 5
d: 6
```

With these yaml files, running `my_app.py` gives the following result:

```sh
$ python my_app.py
a: 1
b: 3
c: 5
d: 6
```

As you can see, `conf1` is being overridden by `conf2`, which is in turn being
overridden by `conf3`.  So, how does this work?  The [defaults list](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/defaults_list) is used to specify the order in which each configuration object
is composed.  In `conf1`, the `@_here_` package keyword is used to specify that
the `conf2` should be merged info the current config group instead of being
included in the `middle` package.  This is documented in [Default List package
keywords](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/overriding_packages/#default-list-package-keywords).
Also of interest is the `@_global_` keyword. Note that one could just-as-well
write `- middle@foo: conf2` instead of `- middle@_here_: conf2` in the defaults list, in which case
a `"foo"` key would appear in the output config with the contents of `conf2`
nested under it.

Just as in `conf1.yaml`, `conf2.yaml` is using the defaults list to specify
that `conf3` should be merged into `conf2` instead of being merged into a
package named `"inner"` (which would have been the default behavior, as is
documented
[here](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/overriding_packages/#overriding-packages-using-the-defaults-list)).

What is the `- _self_` keyword doing?
In a defaults list, this keyword allows for control of the order in which the
current config is merged with other input configs specified in the defaults
list. For example, in the `conf2.yaml` defaults list, writing `- _self_`
*before* `- inner@_here_: conf3` ensures that `conf3` will be merged into
`conf2`, and not the other way around. This `_self_` keyword is documented
[here](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/defaults_list/#composition-order). If `- _self_` is not specified in the
defaults list, then the order in which the defaults are merged with the current
config is:

- using Hydra 1.0: input configs from the
  defaults list are merged into the current config
- using Hydra 1.1: the current config is merged last, overwriting the other configs specified in the defaults list

For reference, see [these migration
instructions](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/upgrades/1.0_to_1.1/default_composition_order)
for moving from version 1.0 to 1.1.

### Use a package header to specify a package.

Using a [package
directive](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/overriding_packages#overriding-the-package-via-the-package-directive)
at the top of a yaml file can achieve a similar result:

In `outer/conf1.yaml`:

```yaml
defaults:
  - _self_
  - middle: conf2
a: 1
b: 2
```

In `outer/middle/conf2.yaml`:

```yaml
# @package _global_
defaults:
  - _self_
  - inner: conf3
b: 3
c: 4
```

In `outer/middle/inner/conf3.yaml`

```yaml
# @package _global_
c: 5
d: 6
```

The `# @package <PACKAGE>` directive specifies where the contents of the
current input config should be placed.

```sh
$ python my_app.py
a: 1
b: 3
c: 5
d: 6
```

This works much the same way as using an `@<PACKAGE>` keyword in the defaults
list (as detailed in the previous section), and the result at the command-line is
identical. One difference between these two approaches is that a package header
applies to all contents of the given input config, whereas using an
`@<PACKAGE>` keyword in the defaults list gives more granular
control over which input configs should be placed into which packages.

Using the `- _self_` keyword in the defaults list is still necessary to ensure
that the merge happens in the correct order (see the previous section for notes
on `_self_`).

Hydra's treatment of package headers is [different in Hydra 1.0 vs
1.1](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/upgrades/0.11_to_1.0/adding_a_package_directive).

### Use a command-line package override to specify a package

The most elegant and flexible way to achieve the desired result is using a command-line package override:
Given `outer/conf1.yaml` as follows:

```yaml
a: 1
b: 2
```

And `outer/middle/conf2.yaml` thus:

```yaml
b: 3
c: 4
```

and `outer/middle/inner/conf3.yaml`:

```yaml
c: 5
d: 6
```

We can use Hydra's powerful command-line [override syntax](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/override_grammar/basic)
to compose the output config:

```sh
$ python my_app.py +middle@_global_=conf2 +middle/inner@_global_=conf3
a: 1
b: 3
c: 5
d: 6
```

Using the `_self_` keyword is not necessary with this approach because the
`+<group>@<package>=<option>` has the effect of *appending* to the defaults
list ([here](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/override_grammar/basic) is a
reference) as opposed to prepending.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer, it has helped me confirm and improve a lot of my understanding about Hydra that I've developed since asking this question 2 weeks ago. The solution I came up with follows along the lines of your last suggestion, having directives at the top of the inner yaml files and overriding them through the call to `compose`. 

However, after your explanation of how to use the `@` package directive in the defaults list along with `_self_` to guarantee overriding happens in the right order I think I will restructure my approach a bit.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)